# Getting RInside example to work with extra linker option -framework

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, rcpp, rinside

I got the RInside example to run and work but I had to manually add the linker option:
"-F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R" at the end for g++ (on Mac Snow Leopard 10.6.8 with Xcode 3.x). It works, but I don't know why. Can anyone say what these options
actually do ? I could not find it on this list: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html

Here is the original code:

```
#include <RInside.h>                    // for the embedded R via RInside

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
 RInside R(argc, argv);              // create an embedded R instance 
 R["txt"] = "Hello, world!\n";  // assign a char* (string) to 'txt'
 R.parseEvalQ("cat(txt)");           // eval the init string, ignoring any returns
 exit(0);
}
```

Here is the linker call as I saw it in NetBeans:

g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/callingrproject build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o -      L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library/Rcpp/lib -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library/RInside/lib -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Libraries -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules -lRcpp -lRInside -lRlapack -lRblas -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R

The last part is what I had to add manually. Without that I got these two linkage errors:

```
Undefined symbols:
 "_Rf_mkString", referenced from:
   Rcpp::wrap(char const*)in main.o
 "_R_NilValue", referenced from:
   Rcpp::wrap(char const*)in main.o
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frameworks are, more or less, a Mac way of packaging applications. These applications might contain code + headers + libraries we want to use. The line

```
-F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/..
```

says, "look in the folder `/Library/Frameworks` for any frameworks that get specified", and

```
-framework R
```

says, "look for the folder `R.framework` in the set of 'frameworks' directories".

Note that the `-framework R` argument is actually handled by `ld`, not `gcc`/`clang`, so you would find more information in `man ld`. The `-F` argument, on the other hand, *is* handled by `gcc`/`clang`. Together, they allow your compiler and linker to find headers and libraries needed.

In particular, on Mac, they are located (by default) as `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Headers` and `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Libraries` -- these are the directories scoured by setting the appropriate framework flags.

More information is available here for the [-F argument](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Darwin-Options.html) and for the [-framework argument](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/IncludingFrameworks.html).

Answer (score 1):

RInside requires R as it embeds R.

This is why you get linker errors about basic R identifiers missing when it is not present.

Now I do not know why these link instructions where not present.  Our `Makefile` in the directory `examples/standard` (from which this first example comes) uses

```
LDLIBS :=   $(RLDFLAGS) $(RRPATH) $(RBLAS) $(RLAPACK) $(RCPPLIBS) $(RINSIDELIBS)
```

and all those variables are set in the `Makefile` itself. This one is

```
RLDFLAGS := $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R CMD config --ldflags)
```

and that should have included R and its library.

Comment: Hi Dirk, The options were there when I built from your examples. So no problem there, I do not understand what the -F option does versus -L. I could not find an "R.a" file (a static library build of R) anywhere in the install, so I guessed this -F option covers this as you point out. Anyway - not that big a deal. Thanks for the info. Good talking to you again - we talked a long time ago face to face in Chicago. I hope you are doing great. Btw. I am very impressed with all the lectures and work you have put into all the different R packages you work on. The community really appreciates it.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words. I do not have an OS X machine, so I do not know how/where this goes belly up, but there are other OS X users on the rcpp-devel list so you could try there.

Comment: I'll have a look when I get a chance.