# Is it possible to "grab"/"scrape" the .Call() output of C printf() within R (or with Rprintf())?

Tags: c, r, string

I'm working with R code that has an interface to C via `.Call()`. The C function outputs to STDOUT via `printf()`. As a concrete, more simple example, I'll follow http://mazamascience.com/WorkingWithData/?p=1099

Here is our C code with outputs hello world via `printf()`, `helloA1.c`:

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rdefines.h>
#include <stdio.h>
SEXP helloA1() {
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  return(R_NilValue);
}
```

After installation via `R CMD SHLIB helloA1.c`, we invoke the function as follows within R:

```
> dyn.load("helloA1.so")
> hellocall = .Call("helloA1")
  Hello World!
```

I cannot access the text "Hello World!" within R as a data structure though. e.g.

```
> vec1 = as.vector( .Call("helloA1"))
Hello World!
> vec1
NULL
>
```

or

```
> library(data.table)
> dt = as.data.table(.Call("helloA1"))
Hello World!
> dt
Null data.table (0 rows and 0 cols)
>
```

Is there any way to "load" the output of `printf()` into R?

I can translate the functions into Rcpp, but will run into the same problem I think with `Rprintf()`.

EDIT: Apologies, I had previously thought `RPrintf()` was a function within `Rcpp`. I have edited the title of this question appropriately.

Comment: Does `capture.output` work?

Comment: @Gregor surprisingly no. Neither does a traditional `sink()`. I think this is in large part due to @ShanZhengYang using `printf()` instead of `Rprintf()`.

Comment: @coatless So, `Rprintf()` would work then? Interesting...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, the issue here is `printf` negates *R*'s built collection mechanisms for output. In particular, there is no C-level 'stdout' file stream and, thus, no output to collect in either Rgui or RStudio. For details, please see [Section 6.5 Printing](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Printing)
 of [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html)

Two possible solutions:

1. Define a macro that sets `printf` to direct into `Rprintf` and  include the [`#define STRICT_R_HEADERS` to avoid errors](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Error-handling).
2. Switch instances of `printf` to `Rprintf` in the offending code.

From here, the capture can be passed off to either [`capture.output()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/capture.output.html), which directly assigns output to a variable, or [`sink()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sink.html), which redirects output to a file whose contents must then be read back in using [`readLines()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readLines.html). The latter makes it possible to have a clear enclose over multiple lines of code to capture output while the prior is focused on securing output present from an inputted expression.

### Option 1

For the first iteration, just define a header that includes the custom define and then include the third party library, e.g.

**my_code.h**

```
#ifndef MY_CODE_H
#define MY_CODE_H
#include <R.h>
// this load R_ext/Print.h.

// #include <YOUR_LIBRARY.h>

// Define strict headers
#define STRICT_R_HEADERS
// Map printf to Rprintf
#define printf Rprintf
#endif
```

**toad.c**

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rdefines.h>
#include "my_code.h"

SEXP helloA1() {
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  return(R_NilValue);
}
```

**toad_example.R**

```
system("R CMD SHLIB ~/Desktop/toad.c")
dyn.load("~/Desktop/toad.so")

helloA1 <- function() {
  result <- .Call("helloA1")
}

# Gregor's suggestion
captured_data = capture.output(helloA1())

# Using sink around multiple function calls to redirect output
# to a single file
sink("sink-examp.txt")
helloA1()
sink()

input_data = readLines("sink-examp.txt")

all.equal(input_data, captured_data)
# [1] TRUE
```

I've implemented this approach in an R package that can be found here:

https://github.com/coatless/printf2Rprintf

### Option 2

This option manually redefines the `printf` functions.

**toad.c**

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rdefines.h>
SEXP helloA1() {
  Rprintf("Hello World!\n"); // manually changed
  return(R_NilValue);
}
```

**toad_example.R**

```
system("R CMD SHLIB ~/Desktop/toad.c")
dyn.load("~/Desktop/toad.so")

helloA1 <- function() {
  result <- .Call("helloA1")
}

# Gregor's suggestion
captured_data = capture.output(helloA1())

# Using sink around multiple function calls to redirect output
# to a single file
sink("sink-examp.txt")
helloA1()
sink()

input_data = readLines("sink-examp.txt")

all.equal(input_data, captured_data)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! This is very helpful, and I appreciate it. Question: `# Using sink around ata`---I don't follow this. Where did the *txt come from?

Comment: Thanks for the help. As a start, I'm trying to integrate the the `toad.c` function into the current C code I'm working with in `/src`. The package `build` works, but install throws an error: `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_R_NilValue", referenced from:
      _helloA1 in bamdb.o
  "_Rprintf", referenced from:
      _helloA1 in bamdb.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`, 'clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1' I believe I follow the rules in the Makevars file, and the R home /include headers are found. `clang` is ok I think. what's my n00b error?

Comment: I bet I'm manually linking to the R headers incorrectly, using Mac OS frameworks. `R.home('include')` gives me `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include`, so I tried using `-I` with this....now, how to fix this...

Comment: Apparently linking to all `R.framework` paths like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19909868/getting-rinside-example-to-work-with-extra-linker-option-framework works, though I cannot load the function `Error in .Call("helloA1") : C symbol name "helloA1" not in load table`. Is there a way to check all available objects to load?

Comment: I've put it into a package here: https://github.com/coatless/printf2Rprintf